# How can I properly add jquery to Eclipse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, eclipse

I'm importing jquery 1.8.17 js files to Eclipse Indigo, and I have been experiencing some problems. There's several errors in js files, like "missing semicolon", etc.

The problem is that I have to meet up deadlines, and I have to solve this issues ASAP. I suspect that I'm doing something wrong like not just copying the files to WebContent folder and referencing it in the jsp page.

As an example, I'm showing the firs line of the js file where several "missing semicolon" and "syntax error" is occouring:

```
*/(function(a,b){function d(b){return!a(b).parents().andSelf().filter(function(){return a.curCSS(this,"visibility")==="hidden"||a.expr.filters.hidden(this)}).length}function c(b,c){var e=b.nodeName.toLowerCase();if("area"===e){var f=b.parentNode,g=f.name,h;if(!b.href||!g||f.nodeName.toLowerCase()!=="map")return!1;h=a("img[usemap=#"+g+"]")[0];return!!h&&d(h)}return(/input|select|textarea|button|object/.test(e)?!b.disabled:"a"==e?b.href||c:c)&&d(b)}a.ui=a.ui||{};a.ui.version||(a.extend(a.ui,{version:"1.8.17",keyCode:{ALT:18,BACKSPACE:8,CAPS_LOCK:20,COMMA:188,COMMAND:91,COMMAND_LEFT:91,COMMAND_RIGHT:93,CONTROL:17,DELETE:46,DOWN:40,END:35,ENTER:13,ESCAPE:27,HOME:36,INSERT:45,LEFT:37,MENU:93,NUMPAD_ADD:107,NUMPAD_DECIMAL:110,NUMPAD_DIVIDE:111,NUMPAD_ENTER:108,NUMPAD_MULTIPLY:106,NUMPAD_SUBTRACT:109,PAGE_DOWN:34,PAGE_UP:33,PERIOD:190,RIGHT:39,SHIFT:16,SPACE:32,TAB:9,UP:38,WINDOWS:91}}),a.fn.extend({propAttr:a.fn.prop||a.fn.attr,_focus:a.fn.focus,focus:function(b,c){return typeof b=="number"?this.each(function(){var d=this;setTimeout(function(){a(d).focus(),c&&c.call(d)},b)}):this._focus.apply(this,arguments)},scrollParent:function(){var b;a.browser.msie&&/(static|relative)/.test(this.css("position"))||/absolute/.test(this.css("position"))?b=this.parents().filter(function(){return/(relative|absolute|fixed)/.test(a.curCSS(this,"position",1))&&/(auto|scroll)/.test(a.curCSS(this,"overflow",1)+a.curCSS(this,"overflow-y",1)+a.curCSS(this,"overflow-x",1))}).eq(0):b=this.parents().filter(function(){return/(auto|scroll)/.test(a.curCSS(this,"overflow",1)+a.curCSS(this,"overflow-y",1)+a.curCSS(this,"overflow-x",1))}).eq(0);return/fixed/.test(this.css("position"))||!b.length?a(document):b},zIndex:function(c){if(c!==b)return this.css("zIndex",c);if(this.length){var d=a(this[0]),e,f;while(d.length&&d[0]!==document){e=d.css("position");if(e==="absolute"||e==="relative"||e==="fixed"){f=parseInt(d.css("zIndex"),10);if(!isNaN(f)&&f!==0)return f}d=d.parent()}}return 0},disableSelection:function(){return this.bind((a.support.selectstart?"selectstart":"mousedown")+".ui-disableSelection",function(a){a.preventDefault()})},enableSelection:function(){return this.unbind(".ui-disableSelection")}}),a.each(["Width","Height"],function(c,d){function h(b,c,d,f){a.each(e,function(){c-=parseFloat(a.curCSS(b,"padding"+this,!0))||0,d&&(c-=parseFloat(a.curCSS(b,"border"+this+"Width",!0))||0),f&&(c-=parseFloat(a.curCSS(b,"margin"+this,!0))||0)});return c}var e=d==="Width"?["Left","Right"]:["Top","Bottom"],f=d.toLowerCase(),g={innerWidth:a.fn.innerWidth,innerHeight:a.fn.innerHeight,outerWidth:a.fn.outerWidth,outerHeight:a.fn.outerHeight};a.fn["inner"+d]=function(c){if(c===b)return g["inner"+d].call(this);return this.each(function(){a(this).css(f,h(this,c)+"px")})},a.fn["outer"+d]=function(b,c){if(typeof b!="number")return g["outer"+d].call(this,b);return this.each(function(){a(this).css(f,h(this,b,!0,c)+"px")})}}),a.extend(a.expr[":"],{data:function(b,c,d){return!!a.data(b,d[3])},focusable:function(b){return c(b,!isNaN(a.attr(b,"tabindex")))},tabbable:function(b){var d=a.attr(b,"tabindex"),e=isNaN(d);return(e||d>=0)&&c(b,!e)}}),a(function(){var b=document.body,c=b.appendChild(c=document.createElement("div"));a.extend(c.style,{minHeight:"100px",height:"auto",padding:0,borderWidth:0}),a.support.minHeight=c.offsetHeight===100,a.support.selectstart="onselectstart"in c,b.removeChild(c).style.display="none"}),a.extend(a.ui,{plugin:{add:function(b,c,d){var e=a.ui[b].prototype;for(var f in d)e.plugins[f]=e.plugins[f]||[],e.plugins[f].push([c,d[f]])},call:function(a,b,c){var d=a.plugins[b];if(!!d&&!!a.element[0].parentNode)for(var e=0;e<d.length;e++)a.options[d[e][0]]&&d[e][1].apply(a.element,c)}},contains:function(a,b){return document.compareDocumentPosition?a.compareDocumentPosition(b)&16:a!==b&&a.contains(b)},hasScroll:function(b,c){if(a(b).css("overflow")==="hidden")return!1;var d=c&&c==="left"?"scrollLeft":"scrollTop",e=!1;if(b[d]>0)return!0;b[d]=1,e=b[d]>0,b[d]=0;return e},isOverAxis:function(a,b,c){return a>b&&a<b+c},isOver:function(b,c,d,e,f,g){return a.ui.isOverAxis(b,d,f)&&a.ui.isOverAxis(c,e,g)}}))})(jQuery);/*!
```

Comment: PS. I did cleans and validates, but nothing have changed.

Comment: Try using the non-minified version. At least then the locations of the errors will be legible.

Comment: @EvilP Yeah, I know and I don't expect that someone do that. The objective is only show what's the code state in the file, and if I could do anything wrong, if the code is expected to be in this way.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, can I find non-minified version at the jquery site?

Comment: You will find it on jquery site but its a more common way to load it from the google cdn website http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jquery

Comment: @darth_alexious what EvilP means it that you should try and format it so that we can read it and possibly help you.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, with the non-minified version the errors gone out. I still with warnings, but the code, now, is legible. If you put your comment as an answer, I'll acept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the non-minified version of jQuery. At least then the locations of the errors will be legible.

It's available [from here](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js).